# Issue with Load More button

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am having some issues with a custom slider on a WordPress website.

The slider works properly for some of the products, however, the same slider does not work on products which are loaded after a "Load More" button.

This is how the content is generated.

```html
<div class="new_full_image-slider">
  <div class="full_image-slider">
    <div class="slider">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="slider_new_link"></a>
      <div class="item_new_slide">
          <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium_large') ?>
      </div>
      <?php foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) { ?>
        <div class="item_new_slide" style="display:none;">
          <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ); ?>" class="attachment-medium_large size-medium_large wp-post-image" alt="">
        </div>
      <?php } ?>

    </div>

    <div class="slider-dots">
      <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
      <span class="slider-dots_item"></span>
      <?php foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) { ?>
        <span class="slider-dots_item"></span>
      <?php } ?>
      <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The JavaScript which updates the classes and styles:

```js
function custom_js_slider(slider) {
    var slideIndex = 1;
    var slides = slider.querySelectorAll('.item_new_slide');
    var dots = slider.querySelectorAll('.slider-dots_item');
    dots = Array.prototype.slice.call(dots);
    var prev = slider.querySelector('.prev');
    var next = slider.querySelector('.next');
    var track = slider.querySelector('.slider');

    function showSlides(n) {
        slideIndex = n;
        if (n > slides.length) {
          slideIndex = 1
        }
        if (n < 1) {
            slideIndex = slides.length
        }
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";

    }

    showSlides(slideIndex);

    prev.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        showSlides(slideIndex - 1);
    });

    next.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        showSlides(slideIndex + 1);
    });

    for(var i = 0; i<dots.length; i++) {

        var this_i = dots.indexOf(dots[i]);
        dots[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            var newIndex = dots.indexOf(event.target);
            newIndex++;
            showSlides(newIndex);
        });
    }

    var threshold = 50; 
    var startX;
    var swipedir;



    track.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0];
        swipedir = 'none';
        startX = touchobj.pageX;
        //e.preventDefault();
    }, false);

    track.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
        //e.preventDefault();
    }, false);

    track.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0];
        distX = touchobj.pageX - startX;
        if (Math.abs(distX) >= threshold){
            swipedir = (distX < 0)? 'left' : 'right';
        }
        if (swipedir=='right') {
            showSlides(slideIndex-1);
        } else if (swipedir=='left') {
            showSlides(slideIndex+1);
        }
        //e.preventDefault();
    }, false);



}

var sliders = document.getElementsByClassName("full_image-slider");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(sliders, function(slider) {

    custom_js_slider(slider);

});
```

And the "Load More" function:

```html
jQuery(function ($) {



  if ($('.post-listing').length > 0) {

      //$('.post-listing').append('<span class="load-more"></span>');

      var button = $('.post-listing .load-more');

      var loading = false;

      var count = $('.post-listing').data('count');

      var full_count = $('.post-listing').data('full_count');

      var cat_id = $('.post-listing').data('cat_id');

      var cat_name = $('.post-listing').data('cat_name');

      var term_link = $('.post-listing').data('term_link');

      var type = $('.post-listing').data('type');

      var ajax_append = $('.post-listing .ajax_append');

      var scrollHandling = {

          allow: true,

          reallow: function () {

              scrollHandling.allow = true;

          },

          delay: 400 //(milliseconds) adjust to the highest acceptable value

      };



      $('.load-more').click(function () {

                  loading = true;

                  var data = {

                      action: 'be_ajax_load_more',

                      count: count,

                      cat_id: cat_id,

                      cat_name: cat_name,

                      term_link: term_link,

                      type: type,

                  };

                  $.post(beloadmore.url, data, function (res) {

                      if (res.success) {

                          $('.ajax_append').append(res.data.objects);

                          loading = false;

                          button.removeClass('load_style');

                          count = count + res.data.count;

                          $('.post-listing').data('count', count);

                          if (count >= full_count) {

                              button.remove();

                              loading = true;

                          }

                      } else {

                          // console.log(res);

                      }

                  }).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, e) {

                      // console.log(xhr.responseText);

                  });







      });

  }
```

Could you have a look and point me to the right direction, please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: @Vel

No, there are not errors caught in console log.

Error log is also clear.

Comment: have you tried calling this ```var sliders = document.getElementsByClassName("full_image-slider");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(sliders, function(slider) {

    custom_js_slider(slider);

});``` after load more successful call

Comment: @Alopwer Yes, I have tried it as a workaround, however, the products which load after the "Load More" button are still not getting updated.

Comment: @KristiyanAyvazov, can you send how the DOM looks like after successful fetch?